# C++: Cannot instantiate a pointer directly

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-image, nullptr

This is an SDL problem, however I have the strong feeling that the problem I came across is not related to SDL, but more to C++ / pointers in general.

To make a long story short, this code doesn't work (edited to show what I *really* did):

```
player->picture = IMG_Load("player");
SDL_BlitSurface(player->picture, NULL, screen, &pictureLocation);
```

I see nothing on the screen. However, when I do it like this, it works:

```
SDL_Surface* picture = IMG_Load("player.png");
player->picture = picture;
SDL_BlitSurface(player->picture, NULL, screen, &pictureLocation);
```

I can see the little guy just fine.

The real problem is that I cannot instantiate Player::picture directly. Even when I try

```
picture = IMG_Load("player.png")
```

in player.cpp, I end up with a nullpointer.

Comment: please show the shortest *COMPLETE* code snippet that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am so stupid. Turns out like I forgot the file extension ".png" every time I tried to store the surface in Player::picture, and conveniently remembered to add it every time I stired it in an SDL_Surface declared in main.cpp.

I had the feeling I was overlooking something *really* simple here, but this is just embarassing. What's a fitting punishment for this?

Comment: :) No punishment necessary. But other answers are right, you should be checking the result for null and handling it properly, not letting it crash from a null. Unless you omitted that for conciseness. In any case, since this is the answer click the green check mark next to it.

Comment: I'm not registered, so I had to wait two days to be able to mark this answer.

Answer (score 0):

What data type is player->picture?  What type does IMG_Load return?  It's really hard to come up with a scenario where saving an expression in a temporary variable changes the result, unless a type conversion is involved.

And I wouldn't call this pointer instantiation.  You're instantiating an instance of some picture type and storing a pointer to it.

Comment: IMG_Load returns an SDL_Surface*, and player->picture is also an SDL_Surface*. I think if it wasn't the same type all around, I'd get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always check to see what IMG_Load() returns...

```
SDL_Surface* picture = IMG_Load("player.png");
if (picture == NULL) {
  // there was obviously some sort of error.
  // what does SDL_GetError() say?
}
```

Some SDL functions return -1 if there is an error. Just check the documentation and make sure you're checking your function returns. These steps make debugging a lot easier.